# Split string in c

Tags: c, split

im trying to split a string in C (Not in C#, C++ or any other kind). I tried using de strtok function, but it turns out that this only works when the limit between each word is a single character such a space, a semicolon....

I have a variable which is a string that contains html code like this:

```
</head>
<body>
Index of /davidgoudet
<ul><li><a href="/"> Parent Directory</a></li>
<li><a href="Horario/"> Horario/</a></li>
<li><a href="Oferta/"> Oferta/</a></li>
<li><a href="Registro/"> Registro/</a></li>
</ul>
<address>Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4                FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at turpialdevelopment.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

And i want to have the  chunks in between the href tags such as Horario, Oferta, Registro inside a variable
but when i tried to use strtok(string, "href") it gives me some weird result which is not the one im looking for.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Use a [parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). He comes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtok` takes a char array of all possible delimiters and it splits based on any of those characters (in your case, splitting on `h`, `r`, `e`, or `f`), which is probably why you are seeing weird behavior.

Is there a reason why you aren't using an HTML parsing library to pull the names?

the libxml html parser is pretty good: http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a proper HTML parser?  [lib2xml has a nice HTML parser in C](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, and I hope will solve your problem.

```
int split(char ***dst, char *str, char spliter)
{
    int str_num = 0;    
    int each_size;   
    int index = 0;     
    int str_index = 0;  
    int start_index = 0;

    while (str[index] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[index] == spliter)
        {
            str_num++;
            index++;
            while(str[index] == spliter)
            {
                index++;
            }
        }
        else
       {
            index++;
       }
    }
    str_num++;

    *dst = (char **) malloc((str_num + 1)*sizeof(char*));
    index = 0;

    while (str[index] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[index] != spliter)
        {
            start_index = index;
            each_size = 0;

            while (str[index] != spliter && str[index] != '\0')
            {
                index++;
                each_size++;
            }

            (*dst)[str_index] = (char*) malloc((each_size + 1)*sizeof(char));
            int cur_i = 0;

            while (start_index != index)
            {
                (*dst)[str_index][cur_i] = str[start_index];
                start_index++;
                cur_i++;
            }

            (*dst)[str_index][cur_i] = '\0';
            str_index++;
        }
        else
        {
            index++;
        } 
    }

    (*dst)[str_num] = NULL;
    return str_num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using strstr() and then offsetting the pointer it returns to you.

```
strstr(big_string_of_tags,"href")+6; //Leaves pointer at the word you're seeking, read up until you see a double quote char.
```

Its not a very elegant solution but if you're constrained to C alone it might be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string comparison function like `strnstr()` to locate substrings, such as begin and end tags. Then you can easily calculate the position and length of the substring you want and use `strncpy()` to copy that data.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* split(char *string, char chr, char *output){
    int seek=0;
    for(seek; seek<strlen(string); seek++){
        if( *(string + seek) == chr ){
            break;
        }
    }
    memcpy(output, string  , seek);
    *(output + seek ) = '\0';
    if( (seek + 1) >= strlen(string)){
        return NULL;
    }
    return (string + seek + 1);
}
```

for use:

```
char *string = "hello world";

while(1){
    string = split(string, ' ', out);
    if(string == NULL) break;
}
```

set the cut value in (out) and returns the pointer to continue the string